# What's an easy way to test out Numpy operators?

Tags: python, numpy

I have Numpy installed. I'm trying to import it on Sublime so that I can test it out and see how it works. I'm trying to learn how to build an image classifier. I'm very new to Numpy and it's pretty confusing to me. Are there basic Numpy operators I can run on Python so I can start getting an idea on how it works?

Comment: can you please mention what exactly you need to achieve? "test out numpy operators" seems like a very broad objective

Comment: I'm trying to learn how to use Numpy as it applies to basic neural networks if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The question is very generic. Numpy has several features. You can play with numpy to carry out several mathematical operation. Please refer NumPy documentation for more information on NumPy. https://numpy.org/doc/1.17/reference/index.html

Comment: Awesome. This is just what I needed thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "numpy operators"? Does it mean the library functions or just numerical operations that apply on every entry of the array?

My suggestion is to start with researching on ndarray, the most important data structure of numpy. See what it is and what operations it offers.